# Can't driver.execute_script() after a except Exception as e

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a loop and a try before it, so after the loop I added

```
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Il y a eu une erreur sur la page {page}: {str(e)}")
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    driver.get("https://fr.ereferer.com/")
    driver.execute_script(ScriptSiCrashLogin)
```

But I get an error

I tried putting the code in raw in the exception and it worked, it's just the script that he doesn't want, I don't understand as they are the exact same code.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: `ScriptSiCrashLogin` - Is this a Javascript?

Comment: How is `ScriptSiCrashLogin` defined?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium sorry I was busy yesterday, it's defined like this ScriptSiCrashLogin = """ code """

Comment: @white
Here the errors : 
https://pastebin.com/ikEXyNmj

Comment: @Shawn from the error I would say so.
Here the error if you want : https://pastebin.com/ikEXyNmj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I didn't solve the script problem, I just found another way.
What I wanted was an infinit loop until my code scraped everything.
So I didn't use the script thing, I changed method and added `while True :`
before my loops, in the except after my loop I added the way to get to the page and after this `continue` which restart my loop.